# SQLite/Postgres SQL Query Distinct column

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql

I have been dealing with this for quite sometime now and I could not be able get around this. It is like this, I have table with `case_no` (alphanumeric), `first_name`, `last_name` and `description`.

What I want do is to select only one row for each distinct first_name/last_name combination.  So, for example

```
     case_no         |         first_name         |         last_name
---------------------+----------------------------+------------------------
     AAAAAAA         |          john              |          doe
     BBBBBBB         |          Dog               |          dawg
     CCCCCCC         |          Cat               |          kitten
     DDDDDDD         |          john              |          doe
```

Given that example I want to retrieve the following rows:

```
     case_no         |         first_name         |         last_name
---------------------+----------------------------+------------------------
     BBBBBBB         |          Dog               |          dawg
     CCCCCCC         |          Cat               |          kitten
     DDDDDDD         |          john              |          doe
```

How do I do this?

Comment: DO you want to perform a DELETE operation or you just want to filter your resultset?

Comment: no, I just want to select them. I am using java to retrieve data then manipulate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT MAX(CASE_NO), FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME;
```

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (2, 3)
       case_no, first_name, last_name
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY 2, 3, case_no DESC NULLS LAST;
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Difference to the version with `max()`:

- Results are ordered by `first_name, last_name`. You may or may not want that.
- Performance is similar. If you need ordered results this is probably faster, else `max()` may be faster.
- You can easily add more columns from the same row.